# Problems running nmap export to file in linux as a cron job / bash script

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I have a very simple bash script that runs nmap and exports the results to an xml file, and the uses scp to upload the file to a server:

```
#!/bin/sh
nmap -sn -oX /home/scan.xml 192.168.20.1-255
wait
scp scan.xml root@myserver:/home/dropoff
```

I can run the script just fine from the command line by typing:
    sh scan.sh

...and it executes flawlessly. However, when I schedule it to be run via a cron job, it fails and returns the following:

```
Failed to open XML output file /home/scan.xml for writing
QUITTING!
scan.xml: No such file or directory
```

I have tried renaming the files, changing the permissions on them, moving them to different directories, but I still get the same error no matter what I do. Any help or direction you could provide would be great. (I am very new to linux - I changed jobs recently and had been working in a 100% Microsoft Environment for the past 15 years, and I've been a bit sheltered.)

Answer (score 0):

As the following post on linuxquestions.org suggests, your $PATH will not be available to the process that executes the cron. Hence the process will not know where to find nmap if you just invoke `nmap` without providing the full location.

https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/nmap-with-cron-does-not-seem-to-work-213294/

To find out where your nmap binary is, type "which nmap" on the server you're running it on. On my MacBook it's `/usr/local/bin/nmap`, but - as usual - YMMV ;-)

If that doesn't work, try the other solution on that same link to troubleshoot.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is because of the path of file on SCP is incomplete.

`#!/bin/sh
nmap -sn -oX /home/scan.xml 192.168.20.1-255
wait
scp /home/scan.xml root@myserver:/home/dropoff`

Comment: Could you add some explanation on what it does and how it could fix the problem?

Comment: @Nikolay Yes, i think it is because of the file on SCP is incomplete

Comment: Very good. Here is one more tip - edit your answer and add this data there. What community is building here - is a knowledge database. People ask questions, we answer them. It is better if you answer will contain all the details that are important and relevant to the problem. Simply giving a command is not that helpful as giving full description of why it happens and what is the solution and how it is going to help. In this way your answer will be beneficial to everyone now and in the future. Look around the site and you will find many good examples of it.

Comment: That was a good suggestion, however it did not fix the issue. I did try running each command within the bash script individually through the cron job, and it is the nmap command that is not working. (the SCP command works great...)

Comment: Try using the full path to `nmap` (for example, `/usr/bin/nmap`).

Comment: I tried that, and unfortunately got the same exact error. I even tried pulling that nmap command out and running it as the only command within the cron job, and it still has that issue. (Also - I am running the cron job as root just to make sure there are not any rights issues...)